# Print 50% or half of the Given String

Tags: c++, string, c-strings

Suppose I had given a string & need to print exact 1st half or 50% of the string in reverse order.

I have tried to set the strlen(s)=n/2 but that asking for:
error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment|.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int t,i,j;

char s[101],b[101];

int main()
{   
    cin>>t;
    for(i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        cin>>s;
        int n=strlen(s)-1;
        for(i=n,j=0;i>=0;i--,j++)
           b[j]=s[i];
        strlen(b)=n/2;
        cout<<b<<"\n";
    }
}
```

should print out 1st half of the string in reverse order

Comment: `strlen(b)=n/2;` You can't do that. You can however put a '\0' at a position in your c-string.

Comment: What the first half of `"abc"` or `"program"` (in reverse order)?

Comment: suppose a given input string: WeWillAttackOnYou will print tAlliWeW

Comment: What the first half of "abc"? I can chk it it is odd or even length, then add a null value

Comment: `int q=strlen(s)/2;while(q)putchar(s[--q]);`

Comment: `#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;` - No, no, no. Don't *ever* do that. Stop learning from whatever source that taught you to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code snippet

```
    int n=strlen(s)-1;

    for(i=n,j=0;i>=0;i--,j++)

       b[j]=s[i];

       strlen(b)=n/2;
```

does not make sense. You should write instead

```
    int t;

    // ...

    size_t n = std::strlen( s ) / 2;

    size_t i = 0;
    for ( ; i != n; i++ )
    {

       b[i] = s[n - i - 1];
    } 
    b[i] = '\0';
```

And there is no sense to declare the variables in the global namespace that are used only  within main

```
int t,i,j;

char s[101],b[101];
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 101;
    char s[N] = "Mahmudul Hasan Suzan";
    char b[N];


    size_t n = std::strlen( s ) / 2;

    size_t i = 0;
    for ( ; i != n; i++ )
    {
       b[i] = s[n - i - 1];
    } 

    b[i] = '\0';

    std::cout << b << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
H ludumhaM
```

Answer (score 1):

With `std::string` and `std::reverse_iterator`, you might do

```
std::string get_1st_half_rev(const std::string& s)
{
    return {std::rbegin(s),
            std::rbegin(s) + (s.size() + 1) / 2};
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/CT5qib)

Answer (score 0):

You can `std::reverse` part of the string you then can `cout::write`:

```
std::reverse(s, s + strlen(s) / 2);
cout.write(s, strlen(s) / 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int t,i,j;

char s[101],b[101];

int main() {
    cin >> t;

    for(i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        cin >> s;
        int n = strlen(s) - 1;

        // Iterate only half the size of string
        for(int k = n / 2, j = 0; k >= 0; k--, j++)
           b[j] = s[k];

        cout << b << "\n";

        // Clear the contents of 'b' so that it doesn't pollute the result of next iteration
        memset(b, 0, sizeof(b)); 
    }
}
```